# Kernel doesn't wait for events

Tags: c++, opencl, xeon-phi

I have a problem with my kernel invocation.
My code looks like this:

```
std::vector<cl::Event> events;
...

queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(arrayFirst, CL_FALSE, 0, sizeOfArray, NULL, NULL, &arrayEvent);
events.push_back(arrayEvent);

queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(arraySecond, CL_FALSE, 0, sizeOfArraySecond, this->arraySecond, NULL, &arraySecondEvent);
events.push_back(arraySecondEvent);

kernel(cl::EnqueueArgs(queue, events, cl::NDRange(512), cl::NDRange(128)), arrayFirst, arraySecond);
```

And when I run it, it doesn't go inside kernel code, but when I change "make_kernel" invocation to this:

```
kernel(cl::EnqueueArgs(queue, arraySecondEvent, cl::NDRange(512), cl::NDRange(128)), arrayFirst, arraySecond);
```

It goes inside kernel, but I don't have surety that memory for "arrayFirst" is allocated correctly, I check documentation of OpenCl 1.2 Wrapper and I found that invocation should looks like this:

```
cl::EnqueueArgs::EnqueueArgs(CommandQueue &queue,
const VECTOR_CLASS<Event> &events, NDRange offset, NDRange global,
NDRange local) //page 42
```

but when I try to pass an address of an events vector I get compilation error, that there is no suitable method with following arguments..

Error:

```
error: no instance of constructor "cl::EnqueueArgs::EnqueueArgs" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (cl::CommandQueue, std::vector<cl::Event, std::allocator<cl::Event>> *, cl::NDRange, cl::NDRange)
              valueOfImageKernel(cl::EnqueueArgs(valueOfImageQueue, &events, cl::NDRange(512), cl::NDRange(128)),
```

Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How about using blocking write (passing CL_TRUE to enqueueWriteBuffer) ?

Comment: I don't want to use blocking write/read because I care about a runtime.

Comment: Your first code snipped should work. What do you mean by `it doesn't go inside kernel code`? How do you know that? Do you get any error, etc?

Comment: By "it doesn't go inside kernel code" I mean that any of printfs doesn't "work" because there isn't print anything on console with first code snippet, with second there is some output to the console. (I use opencl extension cl_intel_printf, to have printf inside kernel).

Comment: Can you post the full code example?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but I will extend my code snippet in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the below line which you don't need is causing you trouble:
`queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(arrayFirst, CL_FALSE, 0, sizeOfArray, NULL, NULL, &arrayEvent);`
You need to call to write to a buffer when you actually have something to write there which is not the case here.

Below the full working example, tested on PHI (just for clarity error handling omitted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <CL/cl.hpp>

int main()
{
    const char *kernel_str{
        "kernel void k1(global int *data1, global int *data2){"
        " int local_id = get_local_id(0);"
        " data1[local_id] = data2[local_id] + data2[local_id];"
        "}" };

    cl_int err = CL_SUCCESS;

    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
    cl::Platform plat;
    for (auto &p : platforms)
    {
        std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
        p.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR, &devices);
        if (!devices.empty())
        {
            plat = p;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (plat() == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "No OpenCL platform found.";
        return -1;
    }

    cl_context_properties properties[] =
    { CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)(plat)(), 0 };
    cl::Context context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR, properties);

    std::vector<cl::Device> devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();

    cl::Program::Sources source(1, std::make_pair(kernel_str, strlen(kernel_str)));
    cl::Program program = cl::Program(context, source);
    err = program.build(devices);

    cl::CommandQueue queue(context, devices[0], 0, &err);

    size_t sizeOfArray = 512, sizeOfArraySecond = 512;
    std::vector<int> varrayFirst(sizeOfArray);
    std::vector<int> varraySecond(sizeOfArraySecond);
    for (size_t x = 0; x < sizeOfArraySecond; ++x)
        varraySecond[x] = x;

    cl::Buffer arrayFirst(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeOfArray*sizeof(varrayFirst[0]));
    cl::Buffer arraySecond(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeOfArraySecond*sizeof(varraySecond[0]));

    cl::Event arraySecondEvent;

    std::vector<cl::Event> events;
    err = queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(arraySecond, CL_FALSE, 0, sizeOfArraySecond*sizeof(varraySecond[0]), &varraySecond[0], NULL, &arraySecondEvent);
    events.push_back(arraySecondEvent);

    cl::make_kernel<cl::Buffer&, cl::Buffer&> kernel(program, "k1");

    cl::Event ev = kernel(cl::EnqueueArgs(queue, events, cl::NDRange(512), cl::NDRange(128)), arrayFirst, arraySecond);

    std::vector<cl::Event> evs(1, ev);

    err = queue.enqueueReadBuffer(arrayFirst, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeOfArray*sizeof(varrayFirst[0]), &varrayFirst[0], &evs); // final blocking read

    std::cout << "Outputting first 10 values: " << std::endl;
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
        std::cout << varrayFirst[x] << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Outputting first 10 values:
0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18,
```

Comment: Yes this looks that this is a problem, I remove all enququwritebuffer which only should allocates data on kernel, and everything works fine. Of course it's good to remember about it for future :) Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Your collection of events is correct, and the kernel call is also correct. Now the question is... are you sure the kernel is blocked?
It can just be slow in starting.

I would check it with a `event.finish()` to the kernel event. 
It your app deadlocks, then it is a problem with the events.

Otherwise it can just be that your executable finishes before the kernel even runs (because it is waiting to the first buffer copy, that takes long). So you will not see any logs, because when the kernel printfs the app is already cleaning up.

Additionally, if you can add all the code for the events it could be useful to debug. Since we are not seeing the full life-cycle of the event array.